# Atualizar arquivos PHP via código

Tags: php, ftp, sincronização

Tenho uma aplicação php no servidor online e tenho essa mesma aplicação instalada em outras máquinas e tablets, gostaria de saber uma forma para que eu conseguisse atualizar minha aplicação no servidor online no caso os arquivos php, js, css, etc ... e consequentemente quando os outros dispositivos conectarem a internet obterem esses arquivos atualizados para a aplicação local neles instalados. Alguém conhece alguma forma de realizar isso?

Answer (score -1):

As máquinas e os tablets tem acesso à internet?

E a base de dados pode ser a mesma que está hospedada online?

Se sim, será que num seria melhor direcionar o acesso da aplicação para o endereço online.

Comment: Não são obrigadas a ter acesso a internet, porém só irá atualizar a aplicação quando acessar a internet. A base de dados vai ser cada um com a sua porque poucas informações são cadastradas pelo cliente no caso os dispositivos. Ter aplicação apenas em um endereço online, está totalmente eliminada essa opção.

Comment: Você poderia criar um script para pegar os arquivos no FTP e move-los para o servidor local assim como fiz nesse código: [link](http://pastebin.com/1hMg4xZr)